# How to get value in another controller - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating some divs using ng-repeat.

See code below :

```js
.controller('meditationsController', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope, $http) {
    var req = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/demo/',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    // Call API
    $http(req).then(function(result) {
        var rawData = result.data;
        $scope.meditationByCategory = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < rawData.length; i++) {
          var meditation = rawData[i];
          if ($scope.meditationByCategory[meditation.main_title] == undefined) {
            $scope.meditationByCategory[meditation.main_title] = {};
            $scope.meditationByCategory[meditation.main_title].name = meditation.main_title;
            $scope.meditationByCategory[meditation.main_title].meditations = [];
            
          }
          $scope.meditationByCategory[meditation.main_title].meditations.push(meditation);
        }
    });
  })
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="(categoryName, category) in meditationByCategory">
      <div class="peacefulness"><p class="para-text">{{category.name}}</p></div>
      <a href="" ng-click="goToDetailPage()" class="customlink">
        <div class="item-content" ng-repeat="meditation in category.meditations">
          <span class="leftSpanStyle">{{meditation.title}}</span>
          <span class="rightSpanStyle">
            <i class="icon ion-ios-information-outline icon-size"></i>
          </span>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I have successfully created the list of divs dynamically according to service response.

Now i want to apply click to each div. and the data that i am getting in service response want to bind the next page. I mean the data on the next page will be dynamic and depend upon cliked div.

please help me to bind the data into another page..

Comment: Create a Angular Service/Factory which is being updated on each click. On the next Page Controller use this Service as a dependancy and you have what you want.

Comment: thanks bro i will try.

Comment: This feels a little broad, you know you need a service and you are not asking for help with a problem when implementing your service.  It feels more like you are asking someone to write the entire service.

Comment: but how can i assign the value to service or factory as i am using loop.. Pls help.. give some hints.

Comment: Please look at : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11 or CodeSchool if you're not familiar with angularjs Services. It looks like you don't know them yet, so it is up to you to learn and use them.

Comment: I have done the same created a service, but i am getting same data always, it's not being updated, any hint ?

Comment: @FerTo i am beginner in angular.  but i have created a service now. but it always gets the data that is being binding at the end div.. any idea ?

Comment: 1. see @andre 's post, you could do as he describes. But you have to configure the router correctly. 2. if you use a Service and it gets "the last one" binded, how are you updating your service? You should have an ng-click="goToDetailPage($index)" (and goToDetailPage Funktion) which is updating your Service first, e.g. something like "myService.update(..)". Than in your DetailPage inject myService via DI in your controller. You could create a "myService.getParameters()" which than would have the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button to your view. Something like:

```
  <span class="rightSpanStyle">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-information-outline icon-size"></i>
  </span>
  <button ng-click="doSomeThing($index)"></button>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.doSomeThing = function(index){
  //do something with category.meditations[index]

  //or go to another state: $state.go("myState", {item: category.meditations[index]})
}
```

**Edit:**

As you say "want to bind to next page" I assume that you want to navigate to another page. Assuming also that you do so by using angulars [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), that means that you want to change state. In that case don't forget to define:

```
url: /myUrl/:item
```

for that state in question. You can access the item in the target state / controller with `$stateParams.item`

Comment: you should mention that you're "recommending" / "using" ui-router here and not native angular